# List to CSV Writer Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write to CSV (i have read the docs/most other threads). but for me only the last line is copied to CSV. This is what I have

```
def writetocsv(l):
   #convert the set to the list
    b = list(l)
    #print b  #checking print b, it prints all values of b
    with open("eggs.csv",'wb') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f)
            w.writerows(b)
```

My input(b) is

```
 [a,b,c]
```

What I expect on CSV is

```
a.
b,
c
```

What I get is

```
c
```

Comment: How did you say, you are passing the values to the function? Is it: `writetocsv([a,b,c])` ? Please show the code which has `calling` of the function. And also the values a, b, and c , have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def writetocsv(l):
   #convert the set to the list
    b = list(l)
    #print b  #checking print b, it prints all values of b
    with open("eggs.csv",'wb') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f)

            for value in b:
                 w.writerow(value)
```

Use a for loop to iterate through the list `b` , write the individual `value` using `writerow`

Comment: didnt work. get this

  w.writerows(value)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

tried this earlier

Comment: use `writerow` instead of `writerows`. Edited the reply

Comment: still no luck, it just writes the last line, nothing else

Comment: `writerow` should work with list. You don't need `loop.`

Comment: tried without loop didnt work. I think the loop is overwriting the first line each time. hence only last line is there.

Comment: how do you pass the list `[a,b,c]`??
do you mean `['a','b','c']`??

Comment: just realised list is 
    ['a'], ['b'], ['c']

Hmm, how do i make list [a,b,c]

Comment: if `l1=['a'] 'l2=['b'] l3=['c']` the use `l1+l2+l3` to obtain ['a','b','c']